# Is it guaranteed which variable will get initialized first if we use comma in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, initialization

Is it guaranteed which variable will get initialized first if we use comma in JavaScript?

For instance, if I have the following piece of code:

```
var a = function() {return 2;} , b = a();
```

Is it guaranteed that the initialization of `a` will precede the initialization of `b`?

I understand that a better practice is to use the `var` keyword each time I initialize a variable. But still I am interested in the answer to my question, since I was not able to find the answer on the internet for JavaScript.

As was pointed out by [Trevor Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711902/trevor-dixon) we can prove that the comma operator in JavaScript and a list initialization are two different things.

```
b = 2, a = 2; console.log(window.a, window.b); //outputs 2 2
var b = 2, a = 2; console.log(window.a, window.b); //outputs undefined undefined
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Saraband, thank you. Your comment seems to be very close to what I am looking for. I will update my question to specify what part is not clear for me.

Comment: I believe if you study the spec (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-VariableDeclaration) closely enough (which I haven't done—it's hard reading specs), you'll find that the behavior you see (left-to-right evaluation) is codified in the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my answer by error above; but yes, [the comma operator first evaluates the left expression and the right one after that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

**Edit:** It seems using `,` to declare multiple variables is unrelated to the comma operator

Comment: I don't think the comma in an initialization list is the comma operator.

Comment: Hm... Could you, please, type an example of the expression which initializes a variable? Because as I understand the expression (which is following a comma) `b = a()` is not an initialization, but a property creation on `window` object.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this snipped seems to work:
`let a = 5, b = a + 5; console.log(b); // 10 `

Comment: @Saraband, it may work a few times or even million of times, but until it is guaranteed by the documentation it is not safe to rely on it. I will upvote you answer. Thank you.

Comment: `(function() { var a = 1, b = 2; })(); console.log(window.a, window.b);` `b` isn't a property of `window`. It's indeed a local variable initialization.

Comment: @TrevorDixon, got it. Thank you.

Comment: @TrevorDixon, actually your point proves that the comma operator and initialization list in JavaScript are different things.